# Yodlee Fastlink iFrame opens Yodlee UI in new tab on mobile web

Tags: javascript, yodlee

I'm using FastLink 4.0, and on a normal browser every thing works correctly. However on mobile web, after loading yodlee in an iframe the yodlee script pops the yodlee UI out into a new browser tab. Since the UI is in a new tab, I'm unable to post messages back to my app from yodlee when a user logs into their bank.

Is there setting or code-level way to force the yodlee script to stay in the iframe?

Answer (score 5):

I figured out that when calling the fastlink js api there is an undocumented boolean key `forceIframe` that you can pass to fix this issue.

```
window.fastlink.open({
    fastLinkURL: '<fastlink-launch-url>',
    accessToken: 'Bearer <your-access-token>',
    params: {
      configName : 'Aggregation'
    },
    forceIframe: true,
    onSuccess: function (data) {},
    onError: function (data) {},
    onClose: function (data) {},
    onEvent: function (data) {}
  },
  'container-fastlink');
}
```

Comment: I found it in official docs: https://developer.yodlee.com/docs/fastlink/4.0/getting-started
But thanks a lot for you investigation!

Answer (score 0):

Using `forceIframe: true` fixes the problem like magic.
It's not documented but I asked on their support.

Comment: your answer does not add any helpful information. It should be placed as a comment.